# How to install SafeGuard Easy on a Macbook running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macbook, encryption

When I install SafeGuard Easy 5.6 on a Macbook running Windows the Installer stops at some point and rolls back. I am aware, that this is not offically supported (http://www.sophos.com/support/knowledgebase/article/107707.html), but due to company guidelines SafeGuard must be used.

I tried Windows 7 64-bit on a Macbook Air (late 2010) with and without Bootcamp.

Is there any way to succeed with the installation/encryption?
If not: Why not? TrueCrypt just works fine and without Bootcamp, there is no software or disk partition difference to any other windows installation.